# Error executing JPQL query

Tags: jpa, jpql

I'm quite new in jpql I'm trying to execute this query:

```
    String queryString="" +
            "SELECT u,sr " +
            "FROM spot_review sr, user u, spot s " +
            "WHERE " +
                "sr.user_iduser IN (SELECT ALL fu.user_iduserto FROM favorite_user fu WHERE fu.user_iduserfrom=:"+User.STRING_ID_USER+") and " +
                "sr.user_iduser = u.id_user and " +
                "sr.spot_idspot = s.id_spot and " +
                "sr.datereview IN (SELECT MAX(sr2.datereview) FROM spot_review sr2 GROUP BY sr2.user_iduser) " +
            "GROUP BY u.id_user " +
            "ORDER BY sr.user_iduser " +
            "LIMIT :"+ServiceConstants.STRING_PAGE_NUMBER+",:"+ServiceConstants.STRING_ROWS_PER_PAGE;

    Query query = entityManager.createQuery(queryString);
```

but I get this error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: . near line 1, column 87 [SELECT u,sr FROM spot_review sr, user u, spot s WHERE sr.user_iduser IN (SELECT ALL fu.user_iduserto FROM favorite_user fu WHERE fu.user_iduserfrom=:idUser) and sr.user_iduser = u.id_user and sr.spot_idspot = s.id_spot and sr.datereview IN (SELECT MAX(sr2.datereview) FROM spot_review sr2 GROUP BY sr2.user_iduser) GROUP BY u.id_user ORDER BY sr.user_iduser LIMIT :pageNumber,:rowsPerPage]
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:54)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:47)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.ErrorCounter.throwQueryException(ErrorCounter.java:82)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.parse(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:284)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:182)
    org.hibernate.hql.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:136)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:101)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.HQLQueryPlan.<init>(HQLQueryPlan.java:80)
    org.hibernate.engine.query.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:124)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.getHQLQueryPlan(AbstractSessionImpl.java:156)
    org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.createQuery(AbstractSessionImpl.java:135)
    org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.createQuery(SessionImpl.java:1770)
    org.hibernate.ejb.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.createQuery(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:272)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:365)
    $Proxy26.createQuery(Unknown Source)
    com.windy.server.dao.jpa.JpaDaoUser.getBestFavoriteUsersOBuser(JpaDaoUser.java:35)
    com.windy.server.service.impl.WindersMainServiceImpl.getBestFavoriteUsersOBuser(WindersMainServiceImpl.java:23)
    com.windy.server.controllers.WindersMainController.bestFavoriteUsersOBuserMobile(WindersMainController.java:93)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
```

The sql query is working but I don't understend what I'm doing wrong in this query...

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

This is not a valid JPQL query, for several reasons:

- `limit` is not supported by JPQL. Use `setFirstResult()` and `setMaxResults()` on the Query object
- given the names used in your query (`spot_review`, `user_iduser`, ...), it seems you're querying tables and columns instead of entities and fields. JPQL doesn't use table and column names. Never. Always mapped entities and fields/properties.
- `select all`, AFAIK, doesn't exist in JPQL
- a `group by` clause without any aggregate function in the select clause (sum, count, avg, etc.) doesn't make sense

JPQL (or HQL) and SQL have similar constructs, but they aren't the same language.

Learn about HQL in the [reference documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#queryhql).